# Repeat function in window in Python

Tags: python, timer, turtle-graphics

How do I repeat this turtle function in the window for a certain period of time? This code draws squares in a circular shape and I want it to restart once it is done and to do this for 3min and 30sec.

```
import turtle
import threading



def draw_square(some_shape):
    for i in range (1,5):
        some.forward(100)
        some.right(90)

def draw_art():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("yellow")
    sqr = turtle.Turtle()
    sqr.shape("triangle")
    sqr.color("purple")
    sqr.speed(1.5)
    for i in range(1,37):
        draw_square(sqr)
        sqr.right(10)
    window.exitonclick()

def timed():
    threading.Timer(208.0, printit).start()
    draw_art()

timed()
```

Comment: What's your problem, just write a loop and have it check the time and if it's been 3:30 quit, and by check the time I mean import time and utilize some function from it to get the time and subtract from the start time and if it equals 3:30 quit

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way you could do it. In your timed function, you record the start time. You then calculate the end time by adding 3 minutes and 30 seconds to the start time.

In a loop, you can continue drawing while the current time is less than the end time.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def timed():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    end_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=3, seconds=30)
    while datetime.now() < end_time:
        draw_art()
```

[Here are some resources](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) on the python datetime module, it's the go-to module for any kind of time or date operations!

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would I make the program restart without re-opening a window? Should I "window=turtle.Screen()" outside the draw_art() function?

Comment: What do you want it to do when you re-start? Do you want it to clear your progress so far and start with a clean yellow screen? Or just continue where it left off?